# Creating boxes in html

Tags: html, css

I've recently got into HTML and CSS and I'm trying to create a website just for fun. So what I've managed to do so far is by creating three boxes in a row. But when I create a fourth box it seats next to the box "three" and it doesn't look good. What I was hoping to accomplish is to either continue with more boxes at the bottom of "one, two, three" boxes. Either with the configuration of three more boxes or two based on the diagram below. All help is very appreciated.

```css
.services {
  color: #1b2049;
  widows: 80%;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 100px;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 36px;
  font-weight: 600;
}

p {
  color: #000000;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 300;
  line-height: 22px;
}

.row {
  margin-top: 5%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.services-col {
  color: #1b2049;
  flex-basis: 31%;
  background: #bcc5d5;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 5% padding: 20px 12px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transition: 0.3;
}

h3 {
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 600;
  margin: 10px 0;
}
```

```html
<section class="services">
  <h1>Just for fun!</h1>
  <p>Type what you want here!</p>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="services-col">
      <h3>One</h3>
      <p>Paragraph for One</p>
    </div>
    <div class="services-col">
      <h3>Two</h3>
      <p>Paragraph for Two</p>
    </div>
    <div class="services-col">
      <h3>Three</h3>
      <p>Paragraph for Three</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

[image]

Comment: What are the red lines supposed to represent? Where should a fourth box go, in that image?

Comment: If I wanted more boxes I wanted them to go to where those red lines are. I tried to copy and paste the section part to a new line and rename the boxes but it is creating an empty spaces in between. Sorry if I'm asking such dumb questions.

Comment: No, don’t worry about that, we all have to start somewhere!

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you want something like this; i've

- cloned your 3 blocks so there are eight
- added `flex-flow: row wrap;` so the `.row` works like a row which wraps overflowing content.
- changed `flex` to `0 1 31%` (never grow beyond 31%, shrink if needbe)
- changed `justify-content` to `center` so the blocks line up in the way you indicated
- removed a `margin` property that was missing its `;`
- added a `gap` to more effectively do the job that that `margin` was supposed to

and to extend it a little, i've:

- added additional content to item#2 (to introduce imbalance)
- added `align-items: flex-start`, play around with that one
- added a `min-width: 150px` so the `flex-shrink` part of the `flex` we added, doesn't go overboard on tiny screens. This will cause the rows to wrap earlier on tiny screens (not after 3, but after 2 or 1 items)
- i haven't done so, but you could a different approach where you add `max-width: 300px;` (or whatever value) to the items, and change that `31%` in `flex` to `auto`. Then it'll wrap after more than 3 items on really big screens as well; meaning the `min-width` and `max-width` control the wrapping.

```css
.services {
  color: #1b2049;
  widows: 80%;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 100px;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 36px;
  font-weight: 600;
}

p {
  color: #000000;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 300;
  line-height: 22px;
}

.row {
  margin-top: 5%;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-start; /* try all 4 of these: stretch, center, flex-start, flex-end */
  gap: 0.5em;
}

.services-col {
  color: #1b2049;
  flex: 0 1 31%;
  min-width: 150px;
  background: #bcc5d5;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 20px 12px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transition: 0.3;
}

h3 {
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 600;
  margin: 10px 0;
}
```

```html
<section class="services">
  <h1>Just for fun!</h1>
  <p>Type what you want here!</p>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="services-col">
      <h3>One</h3>
      <p>Paragraph for One</p>
    </div>
    <div class="services-col">
      <h3>Two</h3>
      <p>In a aliquam magna. Duis vel nunc ultricies, placerat dui sit amet, gravida lectus. Sed dapibus, enim ac commodo aliquam, neque magna sagittis quam, vitae posuere metus nisi vitae mauris. Quisque ac fringilla augue, a rhoncus massa.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="services-col">
      <h3>Three</h3>
      <p>Paragraph for Three</p>
    </div>
    <div class="services-col">
      <h3>Four</h3>
      <p>Paragraph for Four</p>
    </div>
    <div class="services-col">
      <h3>Five</h3>
      <p>Paragraph for Five</p>
    </div>
    <div class="services-col">
      <h3>Six</h3>
      <p>Paragraph for Six</p>
    </div>
    <div class="services-col">
      <h3>Seven</h3>
      <p>Paragraph for Seven</p>
    </div>
    <div class="services-col">
      <h3>Eight</h3>
      <p>Paragraph for Eight</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: No worries; i've extended it a bit with a things you'll likely run into next.